# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.Hosting.SimpleWorkerRequest' to type 'System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest'

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2013, migration

I am getting an InvalidCastException after I migrated my solution from VS2010 to VS2013.

In VS2010 everything works fine, the same code gives the following error in VS2013:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in
>   System.Web.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Web.Hosting.SimpleWorkerRequest' to type
>   'System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest'.

I don't know what to do, couldn't find anything related on the internet.

The error occurs on line 5 in the following piece of code:

```
public static void AuthenticateUser(String UserName, Int32 Minutes = 30, Boolean IsPersistent = true)
    {
        FormsAuthenticationTicket _ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, UserName, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(Minutes), IsPersistent, String.Empty);
        FormsIdentity _id = new FormsIdentity(_ticket);
        var _roles = Roles.GetRolesForUser(UserName);
        HttpContext.Current.User = new System.Security.Principal.GenericPrincipal(_id, _roles);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically, this is not an answer. But it helped me fix my problem.
Therefore I am sharing this with you all, hopefully this will prevent some headache for somebody in the near future.

In Visual Studio 2010 Professional I was running my project using the Visual Studio Development Server using a Specific Port (4302).

In Visual Studio 2013 Community edition i was running my project on IIS Express.
For some reason, I still do not know why, this caused my software to cast a 'IIS7WorkerRequest' to a 'SimpleWorkerRequest' object.

After I switched to the Local IIS Server with a custom virtual directory my error was gone. If there is somebody who can explain this, I would love to know why this is happening. But for now this fixed the problem above.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot cast from a sibling class to another sibling; you can cast from parent to child, or child to parent, but not between siblings.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx

Since both SimpleWorkerRequest and IIS7WorkerRequest inherit from HttpWorkerRequest, you cannot cast between them. I would first ask yourself why you want to or think you have to perform this conversion, and if you cannot find an alternative then write a conversion method to map between them. However, this is usually a good sign that you're headed down the wrong path for your code.

Comment: The error occurs in a piece of code where the cast is not done by me. I've edited my question.

Comment: Is AuthenticateUser a user-defined method? Try breaking out the Roles.GetRolesForUser call to see if the error is actually occurring there. If so, does it occur for all users or just one? The basic problem is that something somewhere is attempting this illegal cast. The assumptions that led to this illegal cast have to be examined before you can resolve it.

Comment: AuthenticateUser is a user-defined method. I've breaked out the Roles.GetRolesForUser and the error occurs here.

Comment: Does it occur for all users, or just some? And to clarify, it's happening when you try to create the Generic Principal, and not when you get the roles, correct? You really just need to figure out what bad values you're passing that are creating this error condition.

Comment: It occurs when getting the Roles. At the moment I am not able to test multiple users. It's happening in an INIT sequence where the admin is being authorized.